# DRY views in Django

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, dry

I have built an application that has a lot of similar views that should be able to use the same base code. However each method has certain unique characteristics at various inflection points within the methods such that I can't figure out a way to structure this to actually reuse any code.  Instead I've created a cut-and-paste methodology and tweaked each method individually. This part of the application was some of the first Python code I ever wrote and know there must be a better way to do this, but I got locked into doing it this way and "it works" so I can't see a way out.

Here's what the base view template essentially looks like:

```
def view_entity(request, entity_id=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return _post_entity(request, entity_id)
    else:
        return _get_entity(request, entity_id)

def _get_entity(request, entity_id):
    data = _process_entity(request, entity_id)
    if 'redirect' in data:
        return data['redirect']
    else:
        return _render_entity(request, data['form'])

def _post_entity(request, entity_id):
    data = _process_entity(request, entity_id)
    if 'redirect' in data:
        return data['redirect']
    elif data['form'].is_valid():
        # custom post processing here
        instance = data['form'].save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('entity', args=[instance.id]))
    else:
        return _render_entity(request, data['form'])


def _process_entity(request, entity_id):
    data = {}

    if entity_id != 'new':  # READ/UPDATE
        # sometimes there's custom code to retrieve the entity
        e = entity_id and get_object_or_404(Entity.objects, pk=entity_id)
        # sometimes there's custom code here that deauthorizes e
        # sometimes extra values are added to data here (e.g. parent entity)
        if e:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                data['form'] = EntityForm(request.POST, instance=e)
                # sometimes there's a conditional here for CustomEntityForm
            else:
                data['form'] = EntityForm(instance=e)
        else:  # user not authorized for this entity
            return {'redirect': HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))}
        # sometimes there's custom code here for certain entity types

    else:  # CREATE
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data['form'] = EntityForm(request.POST)
        else:
            data['form'] = EntityForm()

    # sometimes extra key/values are added to data here
    return data
```

I didn't even include all the possible variations, but as you can see, the `_process_entity` method requires a lot of individual customization based upon the type of entity being processed.  This is the primary reason I can't figure out a DRY way to handle this.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What version of Django are you using? If it's Django 1.3 or higher, you can use class-based views to make your views a lot more DRY.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.3.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/ - each view is a class which allows you to use and reuse functionality it other views. But your view seems to do a lot: it creates objects, it loads objects, it presents multiple different forms, it performs redirects - that's all too much. Does it all need to be done at URL? Otherwise I would refactor it into multiple views.

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I'll try to figure out how to refactor into multiple views myself if no one with some deeper insight happens to provide a helpful basic starting point. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did end up refactoring the code into a base class that all my views inherit from.  I didn't end up refactoring into multiple views (yet), but instead solved the problem of having custom processing methods by inserting hooks within the processing method.

Here's the gist of the base class that inherits from `DetailView`:

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    context = {}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._process(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if 'redirect' in self.context:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.context['redirect'])

        else:
            return self._render(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self._process(request, *args, **kwargs)

        if 'redirect' in self.context:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.context['redirect'])

        elif self.context['form'].is_valid():
            self._get_hook('_pre_save')(request, *args, **kwargs)
            return self._save(request, *args, **kwargs)

        else:
            return self._render(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def _process(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = getattr(app.forms, '%sForm' % self.model.__name__)

        if kwargs['pk'] != 'new':  # READ/UPDATE
            self.object = self.get_object(request, *args, **kwargs)

            self._get_hook('_auth')(request, *args, **kwargs)

            if not self.object:  # user not authorized for this entity
                return {'redirect': reverse(
                    '%s_list' % self.model.__name__.lower())}

        self.context['form'] = form(
            data=request.POST if request.method == 'POST' else None,
            instance=self.object if hasattr(self, 'object') else None)

        self._get_hook('_post_process')(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def _get_hook(self, hook_name):
        try:
            return getattr(self, '%s_hook' % hook_name)
        except AttributeError, e:
            def noop(*args, **kwargs):
                pass
            return noop
```

The key part to note is the `_get_hook` method and the places within the other methods that I use it.  That way, in some complex view I can inject custom code like this:

```
class ComplexDetailView(MyDetailView):
    def _post_process_hook(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # here I can add stuff to self.context using 
        # self.model, self.object, request.POST or whatever
```

This keeps my custom views small since they inherit the bulk of the functionality but I can add whatever tweaks are necessary for that specific view.

Answer (score 1):

Use class based views. You can use inheritance and other features from classes to make your views more reusable. You can also use built-in generic views for simplifying some of the basic tasks.

Check [class-based views documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/). You can also read this [this](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/12/29/class-based-views-django-13/)